# Limit user to a creation of one object in has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, restrict

I am trying to make that my user can't make more than one farm. In my user model, I have:

```
 has_one :farm
```

And in my farm model, I have:

```
belongs_to :user
validate :farm_count_within_limit, :on => :create

def farm_count_within_limit
  if self.user.farms(:reload).size > 1
    errors.add(:base, "User can only add one farm")
  end
end
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in FarmsController#create

undefined method `farms' for nil:NilClass
```

Note that before this farm_count_within_limit I was able to create as many farms as I want with my one user. Is there a better way to restrict it so user can only add one farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_one` will create a singular `farm` method like this

```
user = User.find(1)
user.farm
```

There is no need to additional checking for this in Rails. However this does not enforce at the db level that there will not be a user with more than one farm. The way to prevent that is mostly by creating a unique index. Can do so in a migration.

```
add_index :farms, :user_id, unique: true
```

That will make sure there cannot be a user with more than one farm in the db.

Comment: Let me be clear, I am adding this unique index in the user migration file?

Comment: Doesn't really matter where you add it, can be on farms migration or just a separate migration if you like. It just has to run after the creation of the farms table.